# ASP.NET MVC does not accept valid country codes

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, localization, internationalization

I am using asp.net mvc and I am creating a multi-lingual website using localization.

Therefore I have a bunch of resources for every language and I can change the language in a dropdown menu.
I set the cultureInfo here

```
private void UpdateCulture(int langId)
    {
        string culture;

        switch (langId)
        {
            case 1:
                culture = "de";
                break;
            case 2:
                culture = "en";
                break;
            case 3:
                culture = "tr";
                break;
            default:
                culture = "de";
                break;
        }
            
        var cultureinfo = new CultureInfo(culture);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultureinfo;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cultureinfo;
    }
```

German and English is working just fine, but for some reason Turkish is causing me problems.
I have a `Resources.tr.resx` file and it seems to be not valid.
I know there are some special cases for Turkish like the Turkish-i, but if I use another culture code for my resource file aswell as in the code, it works.
For example, if I change `Resources.tr.resx` to `Resources.kk.resx` ("kk" for Kazakh) and also the CurrentCulture to "kk",   my website is using the Turkish texts from the renamed resource file just like it should.

I spent alot of time figuring out what causes the problem and at least found that dirty solution to make the website work with Turkish language. Has anyone of you experienced a similar problem?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what exactly problems it's causing? I mean the way how it doesn't work - error, it uses wrong culture or other?

Comment: After changing the language to Turkey I am automatically logged out from the session. There is no exception or error and I couldn't figure out where the problem is caused.